# Resetting color in end of PS1 resets commands colors in MirBSD KornShell

Tags: colors, mksh

I have `\033[0m` color code in the end of my `PS1` prompt for resetting, so what I enter won't be colored.

But when I used `ls` I saw that its colors don't work - everything is white. Same for other commands.

How to make results colorful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that actually `ls` in bash is aliased to `ls --color=auto` and all colors work perfectly